# Use of undefined constant project / Use of undefined constant database

Tags: php, mysql

When I submit a variable into a form and submit it to a PHP file which is in turn connected to MySQL server, this happens:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant project - assumed 'project' in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectsday\project-phpfile.php on line 3

Notice: Use of undefined constant databse - assumed 'databse' in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectsday\project-phpfile.php on line 3
```

Why is this so?
Last time I tried, it was fine, but it doesn't work only today.

Line 3:

```
$db=mysql_select_db(project-databse,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

The 'databse' is not misspelled.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `project-databse` is not a valid constant name

Comment: If the database name is `project-databse`, the code should be `$db=mysql_select_db('project-databse',$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());`. If the `project-databse` is a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), you cannot use the dash in its name, rename it like this `project_databse`, for example.

Comment: `"The 'databse' is not misspelled."` - Yes it is, though it may very well be *consistently* misspelled throughout the code and thus not the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function mysql_select_db expects parameter 1 to be a string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

If you haven't defined a string constant named project-databse (it's not possible with -, because the server will try to substract both constants) you should try to put in the name as a string, using ''.

`db=mysql_select_db('project-databse',$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use underscore in your constant name: `project_databse`, instead of `project-databse`
Constants cannot contain '-' character. Your server recognized your costant as two different constants, that's why you have two different notices

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible it was working.

At the moment if you use:

```
project-databse
```

PHP assumes you have 2 constants: `project` and `databse` and you do substraction for them.

So probably earlier it was: `'project-databse'` with quotes.